# Query listing all shared components referenced by a page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create a sql query which returns all the APEX shared components referenced by a page.

Example.
I have a 2 Lists of Values named: LOV_EXAMPLE1, LOV_EXAMPLE2.

I have an application (ID=100) and one page (ID=10) item which is a Popup LOV and it references LOV_EXAMPLE1.

Now I want to create a query which will return the LOV_EXAMPLE1 as a referenced shared component of page 10.

I am using Oracle APEX 21.2.1

I have already looked at the apex views but can't seem to connect them together.

`select * from apex_application_lovs select * from apex_application_pages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether there's *prepared* Apex view which shows data you're interested in, so I'd rather guess that you'll have to dig in to find such an information.

As of example you mentioned - list of values (as part of shared components) - you'd query `apex_application_page_items` (and join it to other views, such as `apex_application_pages`):

```
select p.page_id, p.page_name, i.lov_named_lov 
from apex_application_pages p join apex_application_page_items i on p.application_id = i.application_id 
                                                                and p.page_id = i.page_id
where p.application_id = 10401 
  and i.lov_named_lov is not null;
```